# Highcharts. Async loading part of the data

Tags: highcharts

I have a very simple [graph](http://jsfiddle.net/wux7z0hd/) that shows part of the big body of data. I want to turn it into graph with navigator panel so user can choose what part he wants to see.

When chart is just opened it should show only available data and in navigator bar the same part should be selected. Initially available data is at the beginning. So expected result is:

[image]

My first [attempt](http://jsfiddle.net/0v9a1tp2/) was to use `xAxis` properties:

```
xAxis: {
  ...
  min: 0,
  max: 1000, // all data
  range: 100 // current part
}
```

But in this case on navigation bar wrong piece is selected:

[image]

Also I [tried](http://jsfiddle.net/5ppLfh0a/1/) to set navigator's series with some dummy data:

```
navigator: {
  enabled: true,
  series: {
    data: /* array of length 1000 */
  }
},

xAxis: {
  ...
  min: 0,
  max: 100
},
```

In this case the right piece is selected on navigation bar, but my dummy data is shown there also:

[image]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Axis.setExtremes()](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Axis.setExtremes) on load event and after further fetching data to set the navigator position.

```
chart: {
      events: {
        load: function () {
          this.xAxis[0].setExtremes(0, 100);
        }
      }
    },
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/bjuyj2kk/1/

Comment: So there is no configuration option for this?

Comment: I don't think there is an option for setting initial position of a navigator (there is [rangeselector.selected](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock/rangeSelector.selected) but this is not what you are looking for). And besides, if you are going to fetch the data dynamically, you will have to deal with it with dynamic methods like the one from my answer.